# Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12072 out of bounds for length 127

Tags: java-8, java-17, spring-framework-beans, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

I have been facing this issue after I changed JRE from 8 to 17. On checking different other Stack Overflow discussions, I got to know that upgrading spring-framework version can fix this issue.

this in my POM:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

On upgrading this value 3.0.6.Release to higher version is leading to build failures with:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils

Any other workaround?

Expecting Array Index Out Of Bound to get handled.

Comment: please post the complete stack trace